# Flutter/Swift await sink from synchronous context

Tags: swift, flutter, flutter-plugin, flutter-platform-channel

I'm trying to make use of an async Swift Library for a Flutter application, however, I cannot await the async Swift. The code structure is the following:

```swift
...
    nfcChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
      (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
      switch call.method {
      case "doCGM":
        self.readCGM(result: result)
      default:
        result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
      }
    })
...

private func readCGM(result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
      let device = UIDevice.current
      
      var nfcManager = LibreTools.makeNFCManager(unlockCode: 0, password: Data([1, 2, 3, 4]))

      //perform a request
      let subscription = nfcManager.perform(.readHistory)
          .sink { reading in
             print("Reading done!!!")
             result(reading)
          }

      //sleep(5);
      //print("I am done")
  }
```

The flutter code is

```dart
  Future<bool> _handleIOS() async {
    // Sensor type
    logger.info('Trying to read data from iOS');
    dynamic data = await platform.invokeMethod('doCGM');
    logger.info('Random data: $data');
    return true;
  }
```

This code will not execute the subscription, currently, however, it will happen if the sleep is in the code. Is there a way to await the result without the `sleep`?

**EDIT LOG**

- Integrated Richards Hint, to allow for the result in the async code

Comment: You seem to have lost the `.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)` along the way.

Comment: on purpose, it seems to work without (only)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot wait for anything in a method call handler; you must return immediately. So, how do you return a result that took a while to become available?

You'll notice the escaping keyword in `result: @escaping FlutterResult`. This tells the compiler that the `result` closure may be called after the function has finished (as long as it is called on the main UI thread). The purpose of this is so you can call `result` from, for example, the anonymous function passed to `sink`.

Replace `semaphore.signal()` with `result("test")` and remove the remainder of the function - including the semaphore. (You will likely have to propagate the `@escaping` keyword to the definition of `readCGM`.)

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense; however now the async code gets stuck and never executes. if I add a sleep in the flutter code it will read the data but also not post the result. I've also added the library used to the question description

Comment: Which "async code gets stuck and never executes"? Can you explain "read the data" and "post the result"?

Comment: I've added an edit to the original post, the post the result is the library internal printing

Comment: I've changed the question, I intergrated your answer but still the original point of awaiting the async execution comes up, now just in a different context